# Double quotes in JSON-File

Tags: android, json, character-encoding

I am creating a json-file using following code:

```
JSONObject client = new JSONObject(); 
client.put(key, value);
```

I am sending this json-file over HTTP to my webservice.

If my json-file contains ", on my server it is displayed as a question mark.

I am setting

```
postRequest.setEntity(new StringEntity(this.POSTString, HTTP.UTF_8));
```

in my http-sender-class.

What am I doing wrong, why is the double quote displayed as a question mark?

Comment: what language do u use I mean speaking language

Comment: try to use ISO-8859-1

Comment: Where am I setting the language? German is my native language, but I'm not sure if I am setting the locale anywhere?

Comment: postRequest.setEntity(new StringEntity(this.POSTString, "ISO-8859-1"));

Comment: @sakir If I am setting ISO-8859-1 there's a problem with the webservice when parsing the json, and nothing works. Any other alternatives?

Comment: @sakir Won't be of any use unfortunately, the problem is within the webservice which I cannot change, no problem with the app :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55849/discussion-between-sakir-and-deimos1988).

Comment: Please show a part of your json that contains a ".